# Display colored label with the options in a VueJS dropdown

Tags: vue.js

In my vue component I have following select field.

```
<cs-dashboard-select
 :options="[
 { value: '1', label: 'On duty'},
 { value: '2', label: 'On vacation'},
 { value: '3', label: 'Training'},
 { value: '4', label: 'Sick leave'},
 "
 name="schedule_type"
> Select type
</cs-dashboard-select>
```

There each of these types have assigned a color,

[image]

How can I display this color in front of the option label as following image...

[image]

Comment: Can you show what is the source of the component `cs-dashboard-select`?

Comment: It's a common custom component that I'm using for my drop downs in my app, for this only I need to add this color snippet as well....

Comment: What framework are you using? I think we need to see the source of `<cs-dashboard-select>` so we know how we are going to insert the color. Just like **Vuetify** framework where `v-select` has **template slots** that can insert custom tags via `#append` or `#prepend` slots - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots